# Open a specific website domain page

Tags: windows-8, browser, web

I want to open [airnewzealand.co.nz](http://www.airnewzealand.co.nz/) but I am in the UK.  As a result each time I type 'airnewzealand.co.nz' into the address bar I am automatically redirected to airnewzealand.co.uk.  How do I open the NZ domain page?

I want to access this page because it is much cheaper to book domestic flights in NZ for the .nz page rather that the .uk.

Comment: http://www.houseoftravel.co.nz/cheap-flights/detail/cheap-flights/2014/08/01/other-cheap-domestic-flights#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers get their location information from your ip address, Wi-Fi connection or any location you have set up in your computer or browser. You should be able to easily overcome this by changing your Google location. Instructions on how to do this depending on your device can be found here:

https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/179386?hl=en

Another simple way is rather than trying to open the site directly, search for it first using an anonymous browser like Startpage.com and open the page using their proxy.

If all else fails, you can find a nz proxy to allow you to access nz content directly, with no google modification. One such proxy is this:

http://www.newzealandproxy.com/

And you can look here for a list of nz proxy ip addresses, or do an internet search for proxies from any specific nationality:

http://proxygaz.com/country/new-zealand-proxy/